# S3Client AWS upload Progress

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3

Here is my code .File upload is working fine but now I don't have any idea
about catch the progress of upload file .
I tried many things but not have any solution.

```
 import S3 from 'aws-s3';
    const config = {
        bucketName: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_BUCKET,
        dirName: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_DIREC, 
        region: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
        accessKeyId: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        s3Url: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_s3Url
    }
     const S3Client = new S3(config);

    S3Client.uploadFile(file,name)
              .then(response => {
               this.$vs.loading.close(`#div-with- > .con-vs-loading`)
               this.SaveFile(response,orignal_name)
            })
             .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript SDK there is actually a function named [ManagedUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html) in which this information becomes available.

As part of the `'httpUploadProgress'` event you will retrieve the progress of the currently uploading object to S3 allowing you update your end user with this.

**Example Code**

```
var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
  params: {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream}
}).on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {
  //Do something with progress
});
```

Comment: do you have any syntax solution or example. how i can use this function in my above code .  ?

Comment: S3Client.uploadFile(file,name).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
               console.log("Uploaded :: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');
               })
              .then(response => {
               this.$vs.loading.close(`#div-with- > .con-vs-loading`)
               this.SaveFile(response,orignal_name)
            })
             .catch(err => console.error(err))
      
          }

Comment: i am getting this error ===>
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: S3Client.uploadFile(...).on is not a function"

Comment: Updated to include